# Why is this mass suspended in the air (stable) between two strings?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

As you can see in this image, the two tension forces cancel out. There is a force (weight of the spring itself, 1kgx9.8=9.8m/s^2, 1kgx9.8m/s^2=9.8 newtons), and since the spring is not accelerating (hanging in air) there must be another force that acts in the opposite direction and has the same magnitude. What is this force? where does it come from?

This originally came from a lecture for newton's third law of motion, if you need more context you can watch the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i5readPSsw&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXVCw9WxxEA4yD14k8yskTSj&index=81&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the only forces acting on the spring are the tension in the strings ($T = F_1 = F_2$) and its weight, equilibrium requires that the former have an upward component. If $\theta$ is the angle the string makes with the horizontal, balance of forces in the vertical direction gives $2 T \sin \theta = m g$. With your values $\theta = \arcsin \frac{mg}{2T} = 2.9^\circ$, so this deviation from the horizontal may not be obvious in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent Question
In one sentence: The force which you are looking for is tension in the string itself.
Explanation: Mostly in Newtonian Physics we are dealing with ideal strings(mass=0). Since here you have attached a spring balance which as per your question does have some mass, then it will indeed bent in a fashion such that the tension in the string will have vertical component which will add up and cancel the force of gravity.
However, for small masses the deviation of string from being horizontal is going to be small.